# How to exclude selected filter (facet) from search result?

Tags: solr, solrj, faceted-search

Please suggest how to exclude selected filter from solr search result.

For example, I have selected filter "camera" but still camera (1) is returned in search response. How can I request solr to remove selected filter from search result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your query?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Faceting is simply the aggregation of the values in a certain field for the documents in your result set. If you have 'selected' `camera`, then all your documents will have `camera` and it will show up in the facets.

You can keep track of selections in your application and filter them out from the response received from Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "camera" is a value of the field, say, ProductType, you can do:

```
fq=-ProductType:camera
```

Comment: It won't work because it will exclude all records having ProductType = camera .. I need to filter for ProductType=camera but don't want the selected filter (camera) in ProductType facet list.

Comment: @Omi if you know in advance what to skip, you can skip this when iterating the facet counts. Alternatively, you could apply xml post-editing with xslt transformation: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter